# Gensim.models.phrases.Phrases does not work when input comes from NLTK stemmed tokens

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, spacy

This is my code:

```
def build_trigram_model(corpus):
    corpus = lemmer(nlp(corpus))
    bigram = phrases.Phrases(corpus, min_count=2, threshold=40)
    bigram_phraser = phrases.Phraser(bigram)
    trigram = phrases.Phrases(bigram_phraser[corpus], min_count=2, threshold=50)
    trigram_phraser = phrases.Phraser(trigram)
    return bigram_phraser, trigram_phraser

def punct_space(token):
    """
    helper function to eliminate punctuation, spaces and numbers.
    """
    return token.is_punct or token.is_space or token.like_num

def lemmer(tokens):
    word_space = []
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
    for token in tokens:
        if not punct_space(token):
            word_space.append(stemmer.stem(str(token).lower()))
    return word_space


bigram_phraser, trigram_phraser = build_trigram_model(corpus)
```

This returns something like:

```
bigram_phraser.phrasegrams

{(b'\xef\xa3\xaf', b'\xef\xa3\xb0'): (189, 49.569954185342624),
 (b'\xef\xa3\xba', b'\xef\xa3\xbb'): (189, 49.162979913552),
 (b'\xce\xbf', b'\xcf\x82'): (11, 52.7203947368421),
 (b'\xef\xa3\xb1', b'\xef\xa3\xb2'): (13, 78.54622410336378),
 (b'\xef\xa3\xb2', b'\xef\xa3\xb3'): (12, 74.75279850746269),
 (b'\xef\xa3\xbc', b'\xef\xa3\xbd'): (8, 73.94232987312573),
 (b'\xef\xa3\xbd', b'\xef\xa3\xbe'): (7, 65.46977124183007),
 (b'\xc9\xa1', b'\xcc\x8a'): (29, 64.73618071658315),
 (b'\xef\x9d\xb4', b'\xef\x9d\xb2'): (51, 105.61094674556212),
 (b'\xef\x9d\xa3', b'\xef\x9d\xac'): (26, 53.88736340711684)}
```

When running a new text through the model, no collocations are found.

However, when I use the following stemmer:

```
def lemmer(tokens):
    """lemmatize words"""
    word_space = []
    for sent in tokens.sents:
        sentence = []
        for token in sent:
            if not punct_space(token):
                if token.lemma_=='-PRON-':
                    sentence.append(token.lower_)
                else:
                    sentence.append(token.lemma_)
        word_space.append(sentence)
    return word_space
```

Everything works just as it is supposed to. The dtype returned by both stemmers is list of strings, so that cannot be the problem. Any ideas why this happens? Thanks!

- **Platform:** Linux-4.4.0-1030-aws-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
- **Python version:** 3.6.1

Comment: Your 1st `lemmer()` seems to work on just the items in `tokens`, as if it were just a single text, returning a list-of-strings. The 2nd `lemmer()` works on `tokens.sents`, and returns a list-of-lists-of-strings. That makes comparison harder; you should harmonize their approaches. Then, perhaps check to see if each's output's first list-of-strings appears similar in output/type.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I noticed the embedded lists vs. regular list half an hour after posting this question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Does that mean that''s the source of the problem, and upon correcting that you're getting expected results?